# IntelliJ CMD/CTRL + LMB on <ComponentName> tag not working in VueJS project

Tags: intellij-idea, vue.js

I have couple of projects written in VueJS. I want to be able to navigate from HTML template  element to it's component.vue file using <kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + left click on that element.

My observation is that when project gets a bit larger, this navigation to component stops working (<kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> does nothing) and I have no idea why.

Would you happen to know the solution to this problem?

Comment: This is more likely to get a good answer on the [Intellij issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com).

Comment: it hardly depends on the project size. The issue may be caused by the way components are defined (IDEA may have troubles analysing certain code), broken indexes, exceptions being thrown, etc. In any case, more details are needed to see what's wrong. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, or logging an issue in youtrack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. Its about the way how you export your Components.

Working

```
export default {
  name: 'ComponentA',
};
```

Broken

```
const componentA = {
  name: 'ComponentA',
}
export default componentA;
```

For <kbd>CTRL+LMB</kbd> navigation to work in Vue template, both ComponentA and component that is importing it need to be in the "correct" format.

Comment: There is also problem with navigating to lazy loaded components. Following issue reports that as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33866